# combine table results into columns

Tags: sql, t-sql, pivot

I'm trying to combine results from different (or the same as in this example) tables into separate columns (as a function of for example cat(egory)). As demonstrated in the following example.

Given the following (T-)SQL

```
create table tab(id int, val float, cat varchar(1))
insert into tab(id, val, cat)
    select 1, 2.1, 'A' union all 
    select 2, 4.3, 'A' union all 
    select 3, 2.1, 'A' union all 
    select 2, 8.9, 'B' union all 
    select 3, 1.4, 'B' union all 
    select 4, 3.3, 'B'

select id
    , (select val from tab tab_a where cat = 'A' AND tab_a.id = tab.id)
    , (select val from tab tab_b where cat = 'B' AND tab_b.id = tab.id)
from tab
group by id
order by id

id  val(A)   val(B) 
1   2.1      null
2   4.3      8.9
3   2.1      1.4
4   null     3.3
```

This does exactly what I want, however if cat is variable (let's say based on user input), this route fails. So then I could/must(?) switch to dynamic SQL. That's what I'm trying to avoid. Any suggestions to solve this problem without dynamic SQL?

Comment: If you want a dynamic number of columns, then you'll need dynamic sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, No, you can't without dynamic SQL. But, it will be much more esier if you used the [**`PIVOT`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) table operator, like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM tab t
PIVOT
(
  MAX(val)
  FOR cat IN(A, B)
) AS p
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/77502/1)

And to do this dynamically it will be something like this:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' +
                        QUOTENAME(cat)
                      FROM tab                      
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                     ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                        , 1, 1, '');

SELECT @query = 
  'SELECT *
   FROM tab AS t
   PIVOT
   (
      MAX(val)
      FOR cat IN ( ' + @cols + ' )
    ) AS p;';

EXECUTE( @query);
```

This will give you:

```
| ID |      A |      B |
------------------------
|  1 |    2.1 | (null) |
|  2 |    4.3 |    8.9 |
|  3 |    2.1 |    1.4 |
|  4 | (null) |    3.3 |
```

### [Updated SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/77502/3)

Comment: Thanx Mahmoud the PIVOT operator is the key I was missing